# Merge arrays from object property in an object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

Give an array of objects as below:

```
var objArray = [{'key': 'key1', 'fields': [1, 2]}, {'key': 'key2', 'fields': [3, 4]}];
```

I would like to get an array of merged items from fields property and output should be `1, 2, 3, 4`

I've tried to merge as below. I'm not satisfied with my solution and would like to get feedback's and improve upon my solution. I'm new to JS and typescript. I believe there is better solution with features of ES6. 
Can someone help to improve my solution?

```
function mergeArraysFromObjectArray(objArray){
   let allFields = [];
    for (let obj of objArray) {
      for (let propt in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(propt) && propt === 'fields') {
          allFields = allFields.concat(obj[propt]);
        }
      }
    } 

  return allFields;
}

var objArray = [{'key': 'key1', 'fields': [1, 2]}, {'key': 'key2', 'fields': [3, 4]}];
let allMergedFields = mergeArraysFromObjectArray(objArray);

for(let i=0; i < allMergedFields.length; i++){
   console.log(allMergedFields[i]);  //prints - 1, 2, 3, 4
}
```

Comment: For working code that you want reviewed, see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Check the answer it is what you exactly want

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: The question that was suggested as off-topic should be moved to codereview.stackexchange.com, not closed as Opinion-based.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply `concat` the array and create a new array inside a loop:

```js
var objArray = [{'key': 'key1', 'fields': [1, 2]}, {'key': 'key2', 'fields': [3, 4]}];

var result = [];
for(var i=0; i<objArray.length; i++){
   result = result.concat(objArray[i].fields);
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use [Array.prototype.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Code example 1:

```js
const objArray = [{key: 'key1', fields: [1, 2]}, {key: 'key2', fields: [3, 4]}]
const result = objArray.flatMap(({ fields }) => fields)

console.log(result)
```

Also you can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Code example 2:

```js
const objArray = [{key: 'key1', fields: [1, 2]}, {key: 'key2', fields: [3, 4]}]
const result = objArray.map(({ fields }) => fields).flat()

console.log(result)
```

Also you can use [Array.prototye.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) combined with [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Code example 3:

```js
const objArray = [{key: 'key1', fields: [1, 2]}, {key: 'key2', fields: [3, 4]}]
const result = objArray.reduce((a, { fields }) => [...a, ...fields], [])

console.log(result)
```

Also using just [Array.prototye.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) combined with [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

Code example 4:

```js
const objArray = [{key: 'key1', fields: [1, 2]}, {key: 'key2', fields: [3, 4]}]
const result = objArray.reduce((a, { fields }) => a.concat(fields), [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is how you do it properly :) Es6 baby :) Good job

Answer (score 3):

You can use spread syntax `...` and `map()` to get `fields` property

```js
var objArray = [{'key': 'key1', 'fields': [1, 2]}, {'key': 'key2', 'fields': [3, 4]}];
var result = [].concat(...objArray.map(({fields}) => fields))
console.log(result)
```

You can also add `filter(Boolean)` to remove undefined in case there is no `fields` property.

```js
var objArray = [{'key': 'key1', 'asdf': [1, 2]}, {'key': 'key2', 'fields': [3, 4]}];
var result = [].concat(...objArray.map(e => e.fields).filter(Boolean))
console.log(result)
```