# Merge arrays based on a condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Ok i have a array like the following

```
[
  {data: Array(22), title: '1111'}
  {data: Array(12), title: '2222'}
  {data: Array(6), title: '1111'}
  {data: Array(22), title: '3333'}
  {data: Array(0), title: '4444'}
]
```

What i want to do this if there are objects with duplicate titles (like `{data: Array(22), title: '1111'}` and `{data: Array(6), title: '1111'}`), i want to merge the `data` arrays of the objects with equal titles.

So my final output should be like

```
[
  {data: Array(28), title: '1111'}
  {data: Array(12), title: '2222'}
  {data: Array(22), title: '3333'}
  {data: Array(0), title: '4444'}
]
```

I have tried some lodash functions as well and also javascript filter. I tried forEach ,mapping and etc. But cannot grasp the method to do what i need.

Comment: I would use `Array.prototype.reduce` to create an object which has `title` as key. You should be able to find dozens of duplicates of this or at least very similar problems, e.g. [Merge arrays from object property in an object array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45960288/merge-arrays-from-object-property-in-an-object-array)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array#reduce`.

```js
let arr = [
  {data: [1,2,3], title: '1111'},
  {data: [4,5], title: '2222'},
  {data: [6], title: '1111'},
  {data: [7,8,9,10], title: '3333'},
  {data: [11,12,13,14,15], title: '4444'}
]
let res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, {title, data})=>{
    (acc[title] ??= {title, data: []}).data.push(...data);
    return acc;
}, {}));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the first time i saw '??=' . what does it do?

Comment: @CraZyDroiD It's [logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment).

Comment: @CraZyDroiD It's an object with titles as keys and objects containing title and data as values.